# How insert multiple select values to database?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to insert multiple select values to database.

HTML

```
<select style="width:175px" id="first" multiple="true">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option> 
    <option value="3">3</option> 
    <option value="4">4</option> 
    <option value="5">5</option>        
</select>
</div>

<div class="mid">
<button type="button" class='add'> > </button>
<button type="button" class='remove'> < </button>
<button type="button" class='add-all'> >>> </button>
<button type="button" class='remove-all'> <<< </button>
</div>

<div class="end">
<select style="width:175px" id="second" name="second[]" multiple="true">
</select>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.add').click(function(){
$('#first option:selected').appendTo('#second');
});
$('.remove').click(function(){
$('#second option:selected').appendTo('#first');
});
$('.add-all').click(function(){
$('#first option').appendTo('#second'); 
});
$('.remove-all').click(function(){
$('#second option').appendTo('#first'); 
});
```

PHP:(its only a small portion of the php code)

```
$formvars['second'] = $this->Sanitize($_POST['second']);
$insert_query = 'insert into 'comments'(second) values ("' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['second']) . '",)';
```

Its inserting only the word "Array" into database. Any idea?

Comment: That is because your code $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['second']) return an array, and it can not be inserted this way. Look for batch insert query.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectArr = []; 

$('#first option').each(function() {
    selectArr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Now you can pass selectArr to your server and then check what you getting.

Answer (score 0):

If it's inserting an Array, you should iterate on it via for loop to join all the values in one string:

```
<?php
    $toInsert = '';
    foreach($_POST['second'] as $p){
        $toInsert = $toInsert . $p;
    }
?>
```

The $toInsert string is the one you should write into the DB.